# Moving Folders using iCloud

Tags: icloud

Can I move ENTIRE folders (Pages documents, Numbers spreadsheets, photos) to iCloud, or do I have to move each separately...documents to Pages app, spreadsheets to Numbers app and photos to iPhoto?  I have 10.7.5 OS...can I move entire Folder on new Mountain Lion OS?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the "supported" procedure, but there's a good chance it will work to move a large number of documents to iCloud.

You still have to move documents kind by kind, but not within particular programs.

In the Finder, select the documents (not a folder; the Pages (for instance) that are *in* the folder) that you want moved to iCloud.

Select **Copy** from the **Edit** menu.

Press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to Go to Folder.

Type `~/Library/Mobile Documents/`

If the folder `com~apple~Pages` exists, double-click it; if not, create it then double-click it.

Select **Paste** from the **Edit** menu.

Repeat for the different kinds of files you want to open in their respective apps via iCloud.